# gcc gc-sections option removes crtbegin/crtend objects

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I try to optimize the executable using `gc-sections`, `ffunction-sections` and `fdata-sections`. I also give init function with -u (undefined)  to the linker. My init function and all used symbols added,and other unused symbols are eliminated successfully. Everything is OK.

But `crtbegin`,`crtend` objects are also eliminated which are put by gcc. In that case my executable does not work... Is there any method to keep `crtbegin` and `crtend` objects in the executable.

Note:  `KEEP()` directives exist in the linker for `crtbegin` such as : `KEEP(*crtbegin.o(.ctors))` `KEEP(*crtbegin?.o(.ctors))`  etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is solved. The executable was crashing and giving exception. Since gc-section option was removing the crtbegin functions such as __do_global_dtors_aux call__do_global_dtors_aux,frame_dummy, call_frame_dummy etc. Hence that causes to crash of the program.

But when you keep the init section in the linker : 
"KEEP(*(.init))", then those function are kept while gc-sections option clears other unused symbols. Then my program runs succesfully without any crash.